# How to make widget in the middle of layout stretch to fill the parent in Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, fill

I have an Android layout question. I have a display where I am putting some text into the middle of a view that has a header at the top and three buttons at the bottom. What I am having trouble with is getting the TextView (which is inside a ScrollView) to stretch to fill up the available screen space. If I set the layout_height of the ScrollView to "fill_parent" the three buttons are pushed off the bottom of the screen. If I set it to "wrap_content" it is only as large as is needed to support the text that is put into the TextView.

Here is the XML for the layout I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:text="@string/meetingdetail" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/meeting"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
</ScrollView>

<Button android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:text="@string/naviation"
    android:onClick="meetingInfoOnClick"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button android:id="@+id/mapsingle"
    android:text="@string/mapsingle"
    android:onClick="meetingInfoOnClick"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button android:id="@+id/goback"
    android:text="@string/goback"
    android:onClick="meetingInfoOnClick"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Could someone suggest what would work best to make the ScrollView with the TextView fill up the available space but still allow the three buttons to appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the height of the ScrollView to **0dp** and its weight to **1**.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/meeting"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
</ScrollView>
```

However if you don't plan to have more than one views scrollable you should remove the ScrollView and use:

```
   android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

attribute on your TextView since the TextView is scrollable itself.

Comment: Thanks! Got rid of the ScrollView and added the scrollbars attribute to the TextView and set the height and weight as you suggested and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your ScrollView tag code to..

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1">
<TextView android:id="@+id/meeting"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
</ScrollView>
```

It will work fine, if still you have any problem then tell me. if works then accept as answer.